# Exec excel macro/VBA from php

Tags: php, vba, excel

I have an Excel Spreadsheet with a set of VBA code that does all sorts of manipulation of data in a database. I now need to automate the running of this overnight - using PHP (Don't ask why PHP - there are reasons involving other things).

The code runs automatically on Open.

I've tried all sorts of things but struggling.

I have a .bat file that executes the Excel - and it works fine from command line in windows.
In PHP If I use EXEC or even SYSTEM - it seems to run but does nothing. No Errors either
Even tried to run the BAT file - but nothing.

Running on Windows IIS.

Any help greatly appreciated.

**What I've tried:**

I have a .bat file that contains the following; 
`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe" /e "C:\fls\web\phpTest\DUMMYSsheet.xlsm"`
...when run in cmd or just double clicked in Windows it works fine - and the Ssheet just outputs a log file to say it's run.

In PHP I have tried the following;

```
$cmd="'C:\fls\web\phpTest\runit.bat'";
system("cmd /c ".$cmd,$retVal);
```

Returns a 1 value - but doesn't execute the Spreadsheet code

```
$cmd="'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe' /e 'C:\fls\web\phpTest\DUMMYSsheet.xlsm'";
system("cmd /c ".$cmd,$retVal);
```

Returns a 0 value - but doesn't execute the Spreadsheet code

```
$cmd="'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe' /e 'C:\fls\web\phpTest\DUMMYSsheet.xlsm'";
exec($cmd, $retArr, $retVal);
```

Returns a 1 value - but doesn't execute the Spreadsheet code

Comment: Hi Phil, Welcome to SO. Can you post some code, to help us see what you have tried so far?

Comment: Question updated to add some code.

Comment: Thanks Karl for editing - and sorry I didn't realise that the code lines should be set as such.

Comment: no problem. There's a bit of a learning curve when you first get started.

Comment: Any news on how you got this working? I tried something similar. I can see that Excel opens in the Task Manager but I guess IIS doesn't have permissions to open and run my file on a "desktop". Any input appreciated.

Comment: Sorry Jonathan - we struggled so found a different route and just used a scheduler service to run on the host system.